# Any good sites for Delphi learners?

Tags: delphi

I'm currently in grade 11 (standard 9) and learning the Delphi Programming Language using Delphi 6 and Delphi 7.

Are there any sites where I could access additional learning material?

Comment: What age corresponds to "grade 11 (standard 9)"?

Comment: @Andreas, according to [his or her account profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/448180/darkestlyrics), 17.

Answer (score 4):

[The Stack Overflow question *Good Delphi Blogs?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975586/good-delphi-blogs) is also a thread about good Delphi Web sites.

Answer (score 2):

At [the Stack Overflow question *Learning Delphi*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222/learning-delphi) you can find some materials on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

At this thread:
"[Where are all the Delphi Developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369903/where-are-all-the-delphi-developers)" you can find more Delphi sites with many resources.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think http://delphi.about.com is a good place to start. There are many Delphi tutorials for Delphi beginners as well as advanced ones.